# strange problem calling a function in the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameter-passing

I have a strange problem.

I'm doing my own lightbox gallery in fullscreen. I'm having problems  because when I click in the arrows ( #leftArrowFS, #rightArrowFS )  to move to the prev / next image I just can do it once. If a click a second time it doesn't do anything

The HTML code:

```
    <a href=".path/to/BigImage.jps" class="lightbox">
    <img src="path/small/Image.jpg" />
    </a>    
....
```

and when the  is clicked:

```
$('a.lightbox').click(function() {
        var imgSource= $(this).attr('href');
        lightboxFS(imgSource);
        return false;
    });
```

and my lightboxFS function that it's in a .js file

```
function lightboxFS(imgSource){
...
do a a lot of stuff
...
    $('#rightArrowFS').click(function(){
        rightClick();
    });
}

function rightClick(){
        alert("right arrow");       
        ....
            ....
estadoSetas(array, imgSource);
}
```

The alert just appear once, even if I click hundreds of times. After I click #rightArrowFS if I click on #leftArrowFS, the alert doesn't show too and vice versa.

Any ideas??Thanks

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo. We canot do much with the code you posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought would be that the elements with the click events are being overwritten after an AJAX request, or something similar. If you replace the .click() with .live('click', fn), does that resolve the issue?

As Felix said, though, a fiddle would be helpful.

Comment: It worked. Thanks I didn't know that method. After I read your answer and the documentation from jquery website and it makes all the sense. I have to study more :( I didn't create any fiddle demo because it's quite complex to do it on fiddle. I can't see how a lightbox could work on fiddle.